# Intercept fetch request getting the error "Timed out retrying"

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-intercept

I am using cypress to try and assert that a fetch request has a certain query params. I started by just intercepting and logging the `cy.wait` but even that isn't working and I keep getting the error "Timed out retrying after 5000ms: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: wms. Does anyone know the issue here?

Here is my code and some screenshots explaining the issue.

```
cy.intercept('proxy/service/*').as('wms')
cy.wait('@wms).then(console.log)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your matcher is incorrect and includes an extra `/` following `service`. Your calls aren't coming in as `/proxy/service/?myParam=myValue`, but as `/proxy/service?myParam=myValue`. The following should intercept your request.

```js
cy.intercept('proxy/service*').as('wms')
cy.wait('@wms).then(console.log)
```